# Add some hours/mins to current datetime and get the future datetime

Tags: java, mysql, string, date, datetime

I need to get the get the future timestamp value for a particular time. I will have to add a string value to the current datetime timestamp and get the future timestamp value.

I am fetching current timestamp as below:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I have a string value as `"02:00:00"`, so basically I need to add 2 hrs to this time and get the future timestamp value that needs to be inserted.

For example if current timestamp is: `2019-04-29 16:59:21.43`
and String is `"02:00:00"`.
I need output as `2019-04-29 18:59:21.43`.

Can someone please help

Comment: The `java.sql.Timestamp` class was supplanted years ago by the `java.time.OffsetDateTime` class, as of JDBC 4.2.

Comment: Using a string format of time such as `"02:00:00"` to represent a span-of-time is a poor approach, confusing (ambiguous) and prone to error. Learn about standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) formats for date-time work. Two hours is `PT2H`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Duration diff = Duration.between(
            LocalTime.MIN,
            LocalTime.parse("02:00:00")
    );
    Instant res = now.plus(diff);

    System.out.println("res = " + Timestamp.from(res));
```

Comment: Please don’t use a `LocalTime` as a duration. It isn’t one, so it will lead to confusion and will crash in case the amount to add is 24:00:00 or greater. I know that converting `02:00:00` into a `Duration` without using `LocalTime` takes a little bit more, but it still is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Other than that using `Instant` and `Duration` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is an excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MySQL function `TIMESTAMP` to add a given time string to your timestamp value:

> `TIMESTAMP(expr), TIMESTAMP(expr1,expr2)`
>
> With a single argument, this function returns the date or datetime
>   expression expr as a datetime value. With two arguments, it adds the
>   time expression expr2 to the date or datetime expression expr1 and
>   returns the result as a datetime value.
>
> `mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMP('2003-12-31 12:00:00','12:00:00');`
>   `-> '2004-01-01 00:00:00'`

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Insert a moment two hours from now.

```
myPreparedStatement                     // Use a `PreparedStatement` to exchange data with your database, to avoid SQL-injection risk. Use JDBC 4.2 or later for *java.time* support.
.setObject(                             // Fill a placeholder `?` in your SQL statement.
    … ,                                 // Specify which placeholder. 
    OffsetDateTime                      // Use `OffsetDateTime` to specify a moment in JDBC 4.2. Optionally, your JDBC might support `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` types, while support for `OffsetDateTime` is required.
    .now(                               // Capture the current moment.
        ZoneOffset.UTC                  // Set the offset-from-UTC to zero. We do not need to account for any time zone in this particular business scenario.
    )                                   // Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object.
    .plus(                              // Adds a span-of-time to the moment held in the `OffsetDateTime` object.
        Duration.parse( "PT2H" )        // Specify the span-of-time using standard ISO 8601 format for a duration.
    )                                   // Per Immutable Objects pattern, returns a new `OffsetDateTime` rather than changing ("mutating") the original.
)
```

## Details

> I have a string value as "02:00:00", so basically I need to add 2 hrs to this time and get the future timestamp value that needs to be inserted

That is a poor way to communicate a span-of-time unattached to the timeline.

The [standard way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning, and the `T` separates the years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds. So 2 hours is `PT2H`.

To parse such a string, use `Duration` class for hours-minutes-seconds (or `Period` for years-months-days).

```
String input = "PT2H" ;
Duration d = Duration.parse( input ) ;
```

You can generate such a string.

```
String output = Duration.ofHours( 2 ).toString() ;  // Yields "PT2H" string.
```

Capture the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Add a duration of two hours using standard [ISO 8601 notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT2H" ) ;
ZonedDateTime odtLater = odt.plus( d ) ;  // Add 2 hours to the current moment.
```

Submit that to your database using JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odtLater ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I like to consider my timestamps as unsigned ints. It becomes quite silple to modify them : in your case, try to get an uint representation and just add `2 * 3600 * 1000` to the timestamp, then format it tonthe output you want.